# Find maximum and minimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

I have been trying to find the max and minimum values and make it to a list. I have been using some of the previous forms and it doesn´t work.This is my function:

```
Apa[x_] := x Cos[ \[Pi]/6 ] (x^5 - 2 x^3 + x) - 0.08
Solve[Apa[x] == 0, x]
```

And these are my x-values.

```
{{x -> -1.12682}, {x -> -0.781825}, {x -> -0.344997}, {x -> 
   0.344997}, {x -> 0.781825}, {x -> 1.12682}}
```

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Try: `Minimize[Apa[x], x]` and then try with  `Maximize`. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 4):

Maxima and Minima are characterized by a zero derivative. We may use this to get all extrema:

```
Apa[x_] := x  Cos[\[Pi]/6]  (x^5 - 2  x^3 + x) - 0.08;
ext = x /. {Reduce[Apa'[x] == 0, x] // ToRules}

{-1, 0, 1, -(1/Sqrt[3]), 1/Sqrt[3]}
```

With this:

```
Plot[Apa[x], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Epilog -> Point[{#, Apa[#]} & /@ ext]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Apa[x_] := x Cos[Pi/6] (x^5 - 2 x^3 + x) - 0.08


min = {Values[#[[2, 1]]], #[[1]]} & [Minimize[Apa[x], x]]
```

> {0.999751, -0.0799998}

To find the **local** maximum we have to use `FindMaximum` with a start value (here `0.5`)

```
max = {Values[#[[2, 1]]], #[[1]]} & [FindMaximum[Apa[x], {x, 0.5}]]
```

> {0.57735, 0.0483001}

```
Plot[Apa[x], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[0.02],
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[min], Green, Point[max]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Apa[x_] := x  Cos[π/6]  (x^5 - 2  x^3 + x) - 0.08
convex = Solve[{Apa'[x] == 0, Apa''[x] > 0}, x];
concave = Solve[{Apa'[x] == 0, Apa''[x] < 0}, x];
Plot[Apa[x], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point@{x, Apa[x]} /. concave, 
   Green, Point@{x, Apa[x]} /. convex}]
```

[image]

- `Minimize`

```
Minimize[Apa[x] // Rationalize, x]
```

> `{-(2/25), {x -> -1}}`.